# How to send an object that contains list of another object and each inner object in the list contains an image to controller using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an object like below

```
var formData ={
  title: 'some title',
  items : [
    { 
      title : 'another title',
      image : Image
     },
     { 
      title : 'another title',
      image : Image
     },
     { 
      title : 'another title',
      image : Image
     }
  ]
}
```

this is my c# Model

```
public class Model
    {   
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public List<InnerModel> Items{ get; set; }
    }

    public class InnerModel
    {
        public string Title{ get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }
    }
```

the Image is an image that is uploaded using file uploader.
I want to send it to my controller but when trying to send it as json, the Image inside inner object is null

```
$.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "url",
        data: JSON.stringify(formData),
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",        
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    }).done(function (result) {})
```

what is the best way to send it to controller?

Comment: What do you mean "the Image is an image"? How are you representing that data in the JSON string? What does your c# model look like?

Comment: @gunr2171 I updated the question.

Comment: HttpPostedFileBase is not going to serialize to json and do what you expect. You either need to add the files to a multipart message or encode them as Base64 so they can be carried via JSON.

Comment: It is not clear what `Image` is in your `formData`. Is this Base64 Data or a link to a file path or something else? I think you may not want to Stringify your data.

Comment: @Twisty that is a file that user uploaded using file upload.